# onStartCommand() method calls multiple time even there is no change in my firebase data

Tags: android, firebase

I'm new to android, I'm trying Firebase concept. I'm calling startService method after device getting Registered.

Here is my RegistrationActivity code

```
if (status.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("success")) {
                                    //Displaying a success toast
                                    Toast.makeText(RegistrationActivity.this, "Registered successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                    //Opening shared preference
                                    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(Constants.SHARED_PREF, MODE_PRIVATE);

                                    //Opening the shared preferences editor to save values
                                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();

                                    //Storing the unique id
                                    editor.putString(Constants.UNIQUE_ID, uniqueId);

                                    //Saving the boolean as true i.e. the device is registered
                                    editor.putBoolean(Constants.REGISTERED, true);

                                    //Applying the changes on sharedpreferences
                                    editor.apply();

                                    Log.d("NotificationIntent","Registration success");
                                    //Starting our listener service once the device is registered
                                    startService(new Intent(getBaseContext(), NotificationListenerService.class));

}
```

Here is my NotificationListenerService

```
public class NotificationListenerService extends Service {

    SharedPreferences sharedpreferences;
    public static final String MyPREFERENCES = "MyPrefs" ;
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    //When the service is started
    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Log.d("NotificationListenerService","onStartCommand");
        //Opening sharedpreferences
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(Constants.SHARED_PREF, MODE_PRIVATE);

        //Getting the firebase id from sharedpreferences
        String id = sharedPreferences.getString(Constants.UNIQUE_ID, null);

        //Creating a firebase object
        Firebase firebase = new Firebase(Constants.FIREBASE_APP + id);

        //Adding a valueevent listener to firebase
        //this will help us to  track the value changes on firebase
        firebase.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {

            //This method is called whenever we change the value in firebase
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                Log.d("NotificationListenerService","onDataChange");
                //Getting the value from firebase
                //We stored none as a initial value
                String msg = snapshot.child("msg").getValue().toString();

                //So if the value is none we will not create any notification
                if (msg.equals("none"))
                    return;

                //If the value is anything other than none that means a notification has arrived
                //calling the method to show notification
                //String msg is containing the msg that has to be shown with the notification



                    showNotification(msg);

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {
                Log.e("The read failed: ", firebaseError.getMessage());
            }
        });

        return START_STICKY;
    }
```

when there is no change in firebase value, the notification will getting multiple times by calling onStartCommand while app closed.

Answer (score 1):

`ValueListener.onDataChange()` fires for data changes and also [when the listener is added](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/retrieve-data#value_events). As a result, you will get a notification every time `onStartCommand()` is called and `msg` is not "none".

Because your `onStartCommand()` returns [START_STICKY](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#START_STICKY), if your app is in the background and the system kills your service, which could happen because of memory pressure, it will later restart your service, causing another notification to be posted.

Comment: Hi @qbix, Thanks for the solution. As i am new can u give me exact solution for this issue where i am doing mistake. Thanks in advance